# How to hide the visibility of a TippyJS tooltip that's displayed over video embeds?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have tooltips enabled on [my website](https://online-user-test.tumblr.com/) but I want to hide the tooltip pop-ups specifically displaying over youtube video embeds. I have tried inspecting the webpage and got this following code that only appears when youtube videos are hovered over.

```
<div data-tippy-root id="tippy-8" style="pointer-events: none; z-index: 9999; visibility: visible; position: absolute; inset: auto auto 0px 0px; margin: 0px; transform: translate3d(712px, -688.8px, 0px);"> </div>
```

```
<div class="video">
 <iframe width="700" height="524" id="youtube_iframe" src="LINK HERE" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture; web-share" allowfullscreen style="height: 446.897px;" aria-describedby="tippy-23">
</div>
```

So I tried adding in these "fixes" but the random numbers attached to "#tippy-" change every time, and make it nearly impossible to target and toggle off the tooltip visibility over youtube video embeds for good. I've also tried to target the tooltip elements with "[data-tippy-root]" or "[id^=tippy]" too, but this gets rid of every single tooltip instance on the webpage altogether. What I want is only to target the tooltips that appear when hovering over youtube video embeds. So how can I go about targeting those elements specifically to hide the tooltips displaying over them?

```
#tippy-9, #tippy-8 {
    display: none !important;}
#data-tippy-root {
    display: none !important;
    visibility: none !important;}
```

Comment: Given what you've provided, the last one would be `[data-tippy-root] { ...`

Comment: or `[id^=tippy]`

Comment: @freedomn-m you can use the ^= selector in CSS and plain JS too (querySelector/querySelectorAll)

Comment: *"How do I remove all tippy tooltips"* - why not just *not* include "tippy" in the first place?

Comment: Neither of these worked because they ended up hiding all instances of a tooltip on the website instead of solely targetting the ones displaying over videos. I added a little bit more information to my original post if it helps.

Comment: "*So how can I go about targeting every number possible attached to "#tippy-" to keep this element hidden*" - your request was to hide all instances (I thought it strange given that you talked about media tooltips)

Comment: Can you include a link to "tippy"?  CDN/github/homepage  Google shows numerous that may or may not be the same thing.  How are you initialising the plugin?  See [mcve].

Comment: Sure thing. I'm still working on making a minimal reproducible example to demonstrate the problem but in the meantime, I'm using this Tippy: https://atomiks.github.io/tippyjs/

Comment: How are the `div.video` and `div#tippy` elements related in the document flow? If you establish a selector for tippy relative to video you should be able to hide just the relevant one. For example, if tippy is a following sibling of div (i.e. they share the same parent element and video comes before tippy) the selector `div.video ~ [id^="tippy-"]` will be specific for the ones you want. Tell us where the respective elements are in relation to each other.

Comment: Here is their doc on how to create a tooltip. You should be able to find and solve the problem. Else, you can link your site here and let someone do it.

Comment: Here's the site that replicates the problem: https://online-user-test.tumblr.com/

I still haven't been able to figure out how to target this specific tooltip. They're generally essential for providing more info over some of my icons and text, but I just don't want them showing over video embeds like it displays for one here.

Comment: @online-user I think I figured it out. I have written a new answer below. Try it out. I have tested it on the tumblr site and it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tooltip uses the value of `title` attribute as the tooltip text. `aria-describedby` is just for accessibility. On the Tumblr site, only one YouTube video has the `title` attribute, and only that one shows the tooltip. I removed the `title` attribute and its value (it was `title="The Subway is Flooding`) from the video, and it stopped showing the tooltip. Also, it seems like the Tippyjs somehow hides the `title` attribute from `Element` page of dev tools, so you can't find it there. You have to do it in the source file, in your html file.

So, to stop the tooltip from showing on a certain element, what you need to do is to remove `title` attribute from that element.

**Update:**

The Tumblr site you linked uses the following code to generate tooltips:

```
tippy("[title]", {
    ...commonOptions,
    content(reference) {
    const title = reference.getAttribute("title");
    reference.removeAttribute("title");
    return title;
},
});
```

Basically, it is adding a tooltip wherever there is `'title'` `attribute`. So it comes to how you define the tooltip. It is not possible to modify this after it is created. The "tippy-12" like classes seems to be dynamically generated and so I don't think it is possible to control it with CSS.

So what do you need to do is, unlike this Tumblr site, individually create tooltips for different elements. So, you can control them. This is how you can create tooltips. - [Here](https://atomiks.github.io/tippyjs/v5/creating-tooltips/#:%7E:text=To%20give%20them%20a%20tippy,only%20needing%20to%20initialize%20once.)

Comment: I think this is definitely on the right track because the other youtube video embeds I've tested are unaffected! But I'm not sure how to remove the title from that specific youtube link or any future youtube links that would seem to have a title attached, because I didn't post that video myself and I "reposted" it from another user. So how would it be possible to remove it then?

Comment: @online-user You should be able to do it, Just edit the html file. it must be inside the embeded link, just like that Tumblr site. Where is your site hosted? Does it use WordPress?

Comment: That's the thing, my site is hosted directly on Tumblr. They provide a place to host individual "blogs" there that act as websites, and you can customize them with regular html/css/js. Different users post and repost from each other on there like Twitter for example. So I'm not sure if I have the ability to edit the html of someone else's individual post (that youtube video/link and its title element) within my own code, unless there's a script or something that could read and edit that appropriately.

Comment: I also wanted to add that my inclusion of "#tippy-8" being set to "display: none !important;" does help to eliminate the tooltip appearing over that youtube video. But since this is on a Tumblr blog, the more posts I make then the further this youtube video gets pushed back a page or two and so on. So that "8" at the end of "#tippy-" will change numbers and then lose its relevancy, aka show the tooltip after all. So I wanted to know what would help target it for good, if possible.

Comment: @online-user Javascript can do it. I will try to code one tonight.

Comment: Thank you so much, I heavily appreciate the help!!

Comment: @online-user I have updated the answer. Have a look.

Answer (score 1):

If all the ID start with "tippy-" and end in a random number you can use something like

```
[id^="tippy-"]
```

The `^` indicates that the selector must **start** with the designated value.

```css
div {
  width: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
}

[id^="tippy-"] {
  background: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<div id="tippy-1"></div>
<div id="tippy-2"></div>
<div id="tippy-3"></div>
<div id="tippy-456789"></div>
<div id="tippy-5"></div>
<div id="non-tippy"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
div[id^="tippy-"] {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<div id="tippy-1"> para 1</div>
<div id="tippy-2"> para 2</div>
<div id="tippy-3">para 3</div>
```

You can use attribute selectors in CSS to target elements with IDs that match a specific pattern.

Answer (score -3):

Try this selector to get every div element whose id attribute contains the sub-string "tippy-"

```
 div[id*="tippy-"] {display: none !important;}
```

**NB:** Since you’re hacking someone else’s script (video embeds) you’d better use a FLEXIBLE solution like this (**use an asterisk not a carat**) or you’ll be back to scratching your head again in the very near future.

Comment: I don't agree with you. Sorry. Who says it will always start with "tippy"? You're making assumptions! This is more powerful.

Comment: Who says there are not other stuff that contains tippy. ^= is more SPECIFIC to OP's situation which is better

Comment: @passThru "who says" - OP says, it's their question.   Also seems quite likely that their plugin is creating auto-incrementing IDs (no matter how much of an anti-pattern this is, that's what it's doing), so it's *highly* unlikely it will have a different format. This is ok as an *alternative* solution

Comment: This is the better solution that provides flexibility. The rest are too "hard-coded". We ought to have forethought.

Comment: @freedomn-m. Negative! Video embeds refer to someone else's script he's hacking, that's why flexibility is important!

Comment: Sure, until changed to something like… “X_tippy-24” and you’ll have to go back to programming 101 classes! :)

Comment: Well, it was an interesting argument, but you had to ruin it.  I feel let down.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).